# Grok for log files Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I need to write a grok pattern to retrieve the contents within "**     **"

```
-----Start of script for server sitboap1 at **Fri Apr 17 14:24:19** HKT 2020---------
**user11**   87751      1   0 Apr16 ?        00:00:00 sh **job1.sh**
**user11**   877452  89451  0 Apr16 ?        00:00:00 sh **job2.sh** --server-config= full.xml
**user11**   89772   89452  3 Apr16 ?        00:02:35 **/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64/bin/java** -D[stdd] -server -verbose:gc
```

The log should get the date from the top, user name and job name from the list.
The number of lines under each date may vary.

I cannot quite figure out a grok that fits my requirement perfectly.

It can be a combination of a Grok and a filter in Logstash, but my end expectation is to have these columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below grok filters. There are 2 filters.

**To Get the Date & Time in the header.**

```
-----Start of script for server (.*[a-z|A-Z|0-9]) at %{GREEDYDATA:UserDateTime} (.*[a-z|A-Z])
```

**To get the Contents.**

```
%{GREEDYDATA:User} ([1-9][0-9]{1,10}) (.*) %{GREEDYDATA:execFile}
```

Lastly you can use this [website](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to create grok filters.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but if my log keeps appending in the same pattern, will I be able to use 2 filters ? How would I match my date and values?

Comment: I assumed that you need to parse it line by line;  Since the date is not present in every line you can get it by having multiple match.

grok {
      match => {"date" => PATTERN},
      match => {"values" => PATTERN}
    }